# Annotate a Julia plot with a multiline LaTeXString

Tags: julia, latex, plots.jl

I want to use `LaTeXStrings` to annotate a plot. I have the following example

```
myString1 = L"Some\ \mathrm{text}"
myString2 = L"Some\\ text"
myString3 = L"""
    \begin{split}
        Some\\
        text
    \end{split}
    """
plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
```

So I have the following plot

[image]

Now to annotate, if I do `annotate!(2, 2, myString1)`, I get the expected output

[image]

But if I try one of the multiline strings (which correctly print out in my notebook), I get no annotation. `annotate!(2, 2, myString2)` and `annotate!(2, 2, myString3)`both return the top plot with a message `ERROR: syntax error`

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Trying to help hunt down the answer here. I think the current behavior with respect to the error message is a bug and filed an issue here: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/3883. There might also be a bigger bug at play here beyond the error message itself.

Comment: @logankilpatrick Posting this here since I'm not sure if it belongs in the issue discussion: I tried the code with `backend(:plotlyjs)`, and it looks like there it's just non-interpreted LaTeX that's printed, in both cases. For eg. for `myString2`, the annotation in the plot is literally `$Some\\ text$` (and no errors).

Comment: Same with `:unicodeplots`, but that's more expected. Seems like they're both doing `String(myString2)` at some point, and in PlotlyJS's case that maybe a bug (because of use cases like this, which it should be able to support unlike `UnicodePlots`).